# consul deregister_critical_service_after is not woring

Tags: consul

Hello everyone I have a healthcheck on my consul service, my goal is whenever the service is unhealthy then the consul should remove them from the service catalog.

Bellow is my config

```
{
  "service": {
    "name": "api",
    "tags": [ "api-tag" ],
    "port": 80
  },
  "check": {
    "id": "api_up",
    "name": "Fetch health check from local nginx",
    "http": "http://localhost/HealthCheck",
    "interval": "5s",
    "timeout": "1s",
    "deregister_critical_service_after": "15s"
  },
  "data_dir": "/consul/data",
  "retry_join": [
    "192.168.0.1",
    "192.168.0.2",
  ]
}
```

Thanks for all the helps

Answer (score 2):

The reason the service is not being de-registered is that the check is being specified outside of the `service {}` block in your JSON. This makes the check a node-level check, not a service-level check.

Here's a pretty-printed version of the config you provided.

```json
{
  "service": {
    "name": "api",
    "tags": [
      "api-tag"
    ],
    "port": 80
  },
  "check": {
    "id": "api_up",
    "name": "Fetch health check from local nginx",
    "http": "http://localhost/HealthCheck",
    "interval": "5s",
    "timeout": "1s",
    "deregister_critical_service_after": "15s"
  },
  "data_dir": "/consul/data",
  "retry_join": [
    "192.168.0.1",
    "192.168.0.2",
  ]
}
```

Below is the configuration you should be using in order to correctly associate the check with the configured service, and de-register the service after the check has been marked as critical for more than 15 seconds.

```json
{
  "service": {
    "name": "api",
    "tags": [
      "api-tag"
    ],
    "port": 80,
    "check": {
      "id": "api_up",
      "name": "Fetch health check from local nginx",
      "http": "http://localhost/HealthCheck",
      "interval": "5s",
      "timeout": "1s",
      "deregister_critical_service_after": "15s"
    }
  },
  "data_dir": "/consul/data",
  "retry_join": [
    "192.168.0.1",
    "192.168.0.2"
  ]
}
```

Note this statement from the docs for [`DeregisterCriticalServiceAfter`](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/agent/check#deregistercriticalserviceafter).

> If a check is in the critical state for more than this configured value, then its associated service (and all of its associated checks) will automatically be deregistered. The minimum timeout is 1 minute, and the process that reaps critical services runs every 30 seconds, so it may take slightly longer than the configured timeout to trigger the deregistration. This should generally be configured with a timeout that's much, much longer than any expected recoverable outage for the given service.

Comment: Thank you so much Blake, this is very helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help. Do you mind upvoting the answer so that others are aware it is correct?

Comment: I would love to, but I couldn't. I must have 15 points of reputation :-) I will do it once I get there don't worry.